# Weighting Brand Entropy using Frequency of Purchases

Tags: r, math, entropy

I have a list of purchases for every customer and I am trying to determine brand loyalty. Based on this list I have calculated each customer's brand entropy which I am using as a proxy for brand loyalty. For example, if a customer only purchase *brand_a* then then their entropy will be 0 and they are very brand loyal. However, if the customer purchases *brand_a*, *brand_b* and others then their entropy will be high and they are not very brand loyal.

```
# Dummy Data
CUST_ID <- c("c_X","c_X","c_X","c_Y","c_Y","c_Z")
BRAND <- c("brand_a","brand_a","brand_a","brand_a","brand_b","brand_a")
PURCHASES <- data.frame(CUST_ID,BRAND)

# Casting from PURCHASES to grouped_by CUST_ID
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
ENTROPY <- PURCHASES %>%
  group_by(CUST_ID, BRAND) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  dcast(CUST_ID ~ BRAND, value.var = "count")
ENTROPY[is.na(ENTROPY)] <- 0

# Calculating Entropy
library(entropy)
ENTROPY$entropy <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(ENTROPY)){
  ENTROPY[i,4] <- entropy(as.numeric(as.vector(ENTROPY[i,2:3])), method="ML")
}

# Calculating Frequency
ENTROPY$frequency <- ENTROPY$brand_a + ENTROPY$brand_b
ENTROPY
```

However, my problem is that entropy does not account for the quantity of purchases of each customer. Consider the following cases:

1) **Customer_X** has made 3 purchases, each time it is *brand_a*. Their entropy is 0.

2) **Customer_Z** has made 1 purchase, it is *brand_a*. Their entropy is 0.

Naturally, we are more sure that **Customer_X** is more brand loyal then **Customer_Z**. Therefore, I would like to weight the entropy calculations by the frequency. However, **Customer_X**: 0/3 = 0 and **Customer_Z**: 0/1 = 0.

Essentially, I want a clever way to have **Customer_X** to have a low value for my brand loyalty and **Customer_Z** to have a higher value. One thought was to use a CART/Decision Tree/Random Forest Model, but if it can be done using clever math, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the index that you want is entropy normalised by some expectation for the entropy given the number of purchases. Essentially, fit a curve to the graph of entropy vs number of purchases, and then divide each entropy by the expectation given by the curve.

---

Now this doesn't solve your problem with super-loyal customers which have 0 entropy. But I think the question there is subtly different: Is the apparent loyalty due to chance (low count) or is it real? This is a distinct question to how loyal is that customer. Essentially, you want to know the probability of a observing such a data point.

You could compute the probability of only having bought a single brand given the number of purchases from your data, if the 0 entropy events are your only pain point.

Alternatively, you could determine the full joint probability distribution for entropy and number of purchases (instead of just the mean), e.g. by density estimation, and then compute the conditional probability observing a given entropy given the number of purchases.

Comment: Well worded answer. You also hit the nail on the head - I want to know how brand loyal a customer is (entropy) and the confidence in that loyalty (probability of that entropy given their frequency). These are two different questions, but I want to boil them together into a single metric. Is this possible? Is it advisable?

Comment: Possible - sure, but definitely not advisable. Let assume a score that scales inversely with entropy and probability. Then you cannot distinguish between a high entropy, low probability event and a low entropy, high probability event. If I may ask, why the obsession with a single metric (apart from intellectual satisfaction)?

Comment: I would like to use a single metric as a feature in a larger predictive model (probably a decision tree/random forest/ boosted tree). The model is predicting whether or not a customer is likely to defect from their current brand... that is purchase a different brand from the previous purchase. Naturally, brand loyalty very predictive. Entropy is predictive but only when paired with the frequency.

Comment: Just to give a bit of context... the product is expensive and customers only make a purchase once every few years. Many customers only have one record on file.  Think cars.

Comment: If you have a single order on file, you have no knowledge of their brand loyalty. Any predictive model that claims to get extra mileage by including those data points is lying.

Comment: Exactly... that is why I want to weight entropy by the frequency. That way the truly brand loyal customers (low entropy, many purchases) will have a different score (and hence more mileage in the model) than the artificially brand loyal customers (low entropy, single purchase).

Comment: But then your angle of attack is flawed. You should incorporate the uncertainty when making predictions, not when calculating the entropy. What kind of predictive model are you using?

Comment: I've been tinkering with it using decision trees (rpart) and random forests. The decision trees are just as predictive so I'll probably stick with that.

Comment: I have never worked with decision trees, but presumably there are decision tree methods that allow you to include error bars on your data points?